# C to delphi method conversion of openCV sample code

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a code snippet from openCV example as follows:

```
CvScalar sum_line_pixels( IplImage* image, CvPoint pt1, CvPoint pt2 )
{
    CvLineIterator iterator;
    int blue_sum = 0, green_sum = 0, red_sum = 0;
    int count = cvInitLineIterator( image, pt1, pt2, &iterator, 8, 0 );

    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
        blue_sum += iterator.ptr[0];
        green_sum += iterator.ptr[1];
        red_sum += iterator.ptr[2];
        CV_NEXT_LINE_POINT(iterator);

        /* print the pixel coordinates: demonstrates how to calculate the
                                                      coordinates */
        {
        int offset, x, y;
        /* assume that ROI is not set, otherwise need to take it
                                              into account. */
        offset = iterator.ptr - (uchar*)(image->imageData);
        y = offset/image->widthStep;
        x = (offset - y*image->widthStep)/(3*sizeof(uchar)
                                      /* size of pixel */);
        printf("(%d,%d)\n", x, y );
        }
    }
    return cvScalar( blue_sum, green_sum, red_sum );
}
```

I got stuck on the line:

```
offset = iterator.ptr - (uchar*)(image->imageData);
```

Iterator structure is:

```
PCvLineIterator = ^TCvLineIterator;
TCvLineIterator = packed record
  ptr: ^UCHAR;
  err: Integer;
  plus_delta: Integer;
  minus_delta: Integer;
  plus_step: Integer;
  minus_step: Integer;
end;
```

image->imageData is

```
imageData: PByte;
```

Could someone help me convert the offset line to delphi?

Thanks!

Comment: We are glad to help, but please show some effort first. What are the problems?

Comment: What does your delphi code look like and why did you pack the record?

Comment: I would like to calculate offset. To be honest I don't get the point what is done on that line and how it should be written in delphi. I have migrated the structure from C, method signature and that seems to work, only that offset

Comment: I made some research. image->imageData points to the beginning of picture data. Ptr is the pointer to the Point position within image->imageData. So I need to substract the both to see on which position the point is in the data. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that calculates `offset` is simply calculating the number of bytes between the pointers `iterator.ptr` and `image->imageData`. Assuming you are using the same variable names a Delphi version of that code would be like this:

```
offset := PByte(iterator.ptr) - image.ImageData;
```

However, since you are using an older version of Delphi, the above code will not compile. Older Delphi versions (pre Delphi 2009) don't permit pointer arithmetic on types other than `PAnsiChar`. So you will need to write it like this:

```
offset := PAnsiChar(iterator.ptr) - PAnsiChar(image.ImageData);
```

I suspect that what is confusing you in the C code is `(uchar*)`. That is the C syntax for a type cast.

---

As an aside, it is a mistake to use `packed` records for OpenCV structs. If you take a look at the C header files you will see that these structs are not packed. This is benign in the case of `CvLineIterator` since it has no padding, but you will get caught out somewhere down the line if you get into the bad habit of packing structs that should not be packed.

Comment: I get: Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: @John Yes, I'm on top of that. I noticed that you are using an older Delphi version which does not support pointer arithmetic on types other than PAnsiChar. See the second line of code.